# Solving $\sin \theta_1+\sin \theta_2=\sin \theta_3+c_1$ and $\cos \theta_1+\cos \theta_2=\cos\theta_3+c_2$ for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$

Tags: trigonometry, nonlinear-system

For these two equations:
$$\begin{align}
\sin \theta_1+\sin \theta_2&=\sin \theta_3+c_1 \\
\cos \theta_1+\cos \theta_2&=\cos\theta_3+c_2
\end{align}$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants.

How can I put $\theta_1$ as a function of $\theta_3$ only, and $\theta_2$ as a function of $\theta_3$ only?

Comment: $|\sin\theta_2|=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta_2}=\sqrt{1-(\cos\theta_3+c_2-\cos\theta_1)^2}$, to substitute in the first equation

Comment: You can simplify the situation slightly by defining, say, $r_1:=\sin\theta_3+c_1$ and $r_2:=\cos\theta_3+c_2$. If you further define $x_1:=90^\circ-\theta_1$ and (for the sake of matching) $x_2:=\theta_2$, then you have the system $$\begin{align}\cos x_1+\sin x_2&=r_1\\ \sin x_1+\cos x_2&=r_2\end{align}$$ From here, you can consult, eg, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3681788/409), which solves a more-general system with coefficients on the trig functions; simply take $p_i=q_i=1$ there, and the resulting monster quartic equation will reduce to a manageable quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there are algebraic ways to solve this. But this problem is easier to deal with geometrically:
[image]

If $B=(x,y)=(c_2+\cos\theta_3,c_1+\sin\theta_3)$, then it's easy to see that:
$$
\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}2 = \arg B=\mathop{\mathrm{sign}}y \ \arccos\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\\
\cos{\frac{\theta_2-\theta_1}2} = \frac{|B|}2=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}2
$$

This assumes, that $-\pi<\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}2<\pi$ and $0\le\theta_2-\theta_1\le\pi$. If you need other assumptions, you can modify the result accordingly.